# Can I use an RIBU1C to switch a 110v fan?

Tags: switching, home-automation

I recently set up a millivolt switched gas heater with an Ecobee3 thermostat. I used an [RIBU1C relay](https://s3.amazonaws.com/s3.supplyhouse.com/product_files/RIBU1C-product.pdf) to accomplish this (Ecobee wants to switch a 24VAC circuit, and the gas heater wants a millivolt circuit switch). That all works great. (I followed [this guide](https://medium.com/@ZekeS/using-an-ecobee-thermostat-with-a-millivolt-heating-system-217047db5d56).)

Now I have the bright idea of turning on a 110v fan every time the heater turns on, to better distribute heat from the heater. I'm looking at the 110V leads on the RIBU1C and it seems like I could just wire that up like a 110V light switch inline to the hot wire on the fan?

[image: Basically this is how I think the system would work]

I would appreciate advice on whether I am misunderstanding how the 110V lines on the RIBU1C work (maybe they are for 110V signal input and not designed to switch on/off 110V lines?)

I have decent/safe household 110V electrical knowledge (I can safely install light switches, direct wired overhead fans, etc), and a smattering of electronics knowledge. So I'm comfortable making the 110V wiring from the wall to the fan safe. I just want some external input to make sure I don't let the magic smoke out of my relay, or the Ecobee, or otherwise do something dumb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proposed use of that relay looks fine.

The key item in the relay specifications is "1/3 HP @ 120-240 Vac (N/O)." That says that a normally open relay contact of that relay is rated for controlling a 1/3 horsepower motor powered from a voltage from 120 to 240 volts. 1/3 Hp is about 250 watts mechanical output of the motor. Your fan does not likely exceed that power level.

Comment: It turns out that written on the box are instructions that the the 24VAC and 110VAC switches are not to be used at the same time. So I'll need to add a second switch to the circuit to activate a fan. I'm just adding this to be sure someone else doesn't try to put a load on both switches at the same time: the box says _not_ to do that.